# Python can not access S3 bucket through EC2 instance

Tags: python, apache-spark, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, pyspark

I have an Amazon EC2 instance running which has IAM policy that is open to invoke any resources which is proven by invoking a public S3 bucket. But, if I create one S3 bucket myself(mybucket with some .csv files) and provide a bucket policy

```
{
    "Id": "Policy112324099371",
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt3309232",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/*",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

to be invoked by the EC2 user, I am getting the below error.

```
    com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Status Code: 400, AWS Service: Amazon S3, AWS Request ID: <REQUEST ID>, AWS Error Code: null, AWS Error Message: Bad Request, S3 Extended Request ID: <EXTENDED REQUEST ID>
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:798)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:421)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:232)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:3528)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.headBucket(AmazonS3Client.java:1031)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.doesBucketExist(AmazonS3Client.java:994)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.initialize(S3AFileSystem.java:297)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2669)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:94)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2703)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2685)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:373)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:295)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$14.apply(DataSource.scala:350)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$14.apply(DataSource.scala:348)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.flatMap(List.scala:344)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:348)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:178)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.csv(DataFrameReader.scala:533)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor91.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

The invocation code is -

```
sqlc = SQLContext(sc)
df=sqlc.read.csv('s3a://mybucket/*', header='true', inferSchema='true')
```

Any pointers why I get this 400 error code?

Comment: Might be helpful: [How to read parquet data from S3 to spark dataframe Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44629156/174777) and [Working with S3 and Spark Locally – Matthew Powers – Medium](https://medium.com/@mrpowers/working-with-s3-and-spark-locally-1374bb0a354)

Comment: Thanks for that. The issue lies more on configuring the bucket policy as I could access another bucket with similar s3a URL convention. Also, if I give some random bucket name, I get error saying bucket does not exist.

Comment: I can access this URL though: "s3a://landsat-pds/scene_list.gz"

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue! The issue appears to be with the location of the S3 bucket. After I changed the location from EU(London) to EU(Ireland), it started working.